# How to get WHO disease ICD description according to ICD code?

Tags: c#

i want to get ICD disease descriptions and other values using icd code in c#, how can i get. and i want to use this functionality in my web application in mvc c#.

Comment: I've not got even a clue as to what ICD is. Either way, we're not a code-writing service.

Comment: WHO deceases ICD Codes and their Descriptions LIKE ICD-10-CM Code Diagnosis
M06.0 Rheumatoid arthritis without rheumatoid factor
M06.03 Rheumatoid arthritis without rheumatoid factor of the wrist
M06.032 Rheumatoid arthritis without rheumatoid factor of the left wrist
M06.031 Rheumatoid arthritis without rheumatoid factor of the right wrist @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public string GetICDCode(string ICDCode)
    {
        DiagnosisModel model = new DiagnosisModel();
        String postURL = string.Format("http://icd10api.com/?code={0}&desc=short&r=json", ICDCode);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postURL);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string jsonText;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            jsonText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return jsonText;

    }
```

A Complete Reference on 
http://stackoperation.com/get-decease-icd-code-in-c-using-icd10-api/